# Django - TypeError - NoneType' object is not iterable - Dont understand why Object is being recognized as None

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, django-authentication, django-channels

first question here as I am relatively new to programming, and I have been breaking my head for Days over an error I am getting, which is the following:

The purpose is creating a user to user "messaging" using Django Channels as per an online tutorial which I want to implement to my django project.  I have narrowed down the error as a problem with the Auth model I had in place vs how I am querying it, a URL / path syntax Error or a typo? I am lost after so much research.

When I type in localhost:8000/messages/jarturoch in the browser I get the following error:

> TypeError at /messages/jarturoch/ 
>   'NoneType' object is not iterable 
>   Request Method: GET 
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/messages/jarturoch/ 
>   Django Version: 2.0.2 
>   Exception Type: TypeError 
>   Exception Value:    
>   'NoneType' object is not iterable 
>   Exception Location:  
> /home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/quekieres-main/qkchat/views.py in get_object, line 26 
>   Python Executable:   
>  /home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/bin/python
>   Python Version: 3.6.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/quekieres-main',
>   '/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python36.zip',
>    '/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6',
>    '/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>    '/home/jarturoch/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
>    '/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

The console gives me this 500 Internal Server Error before the traceback:

> 2018/07/19 14:08:20] **HTTP GET** /messages/jarturoch/ **500** [0.16, 127.0.0.1:53212]
>   Internal Server Error: /messages/jarturoch/

**jarturoch** in this case is the main Logged In User.

If I type: localhost:8000/messages/jones
**jones** being another registered user.

I get a functioning page with a chat as follows:

[chat page for other_username I assume as this is not the logged in user, which is functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrfbs.png)

Here is traceback from the django debug:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
>     69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
>     52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
>     89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
>     105.         self.object = self.get_object()
>
> **File "/home/jarturoch/Desktop/pythondev/django_projects/quekieres-main/qkchat/views.py", line 26 in get_object 
>
>   obj, created    = > Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)**
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /messages/jarturoch/
>   Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

**Settings.py** file includes the following snippets:

```
#mainproject settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# my apps
'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
'ecommerce',
'qkchat',
# 3rd party apps
'social_django',
'channels',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'quekieres.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'quekieres.wsgi.application'
# Channels app config - asgi
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'quekieres.routing.application'



STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quekieres/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

try:
from .local_settings import *
    except ImportError:
pass


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',  # for Facebook auth
 'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth', # for twitter auth

 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # ensures user can still login through django auth model backend
)

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''

SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = ''


CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
            # "hosts": [(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')]  FOR PRODUCTION
        },
    },
}
```

**routing.py** - resides in main project app (where settings.py is located)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator

from qkchat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                    url(r'^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ChatConsumer),    
            ])
        )
    )
})
```

**urls.py** - from Main App

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from products import views
# from products.views import ProductListView, ProductDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    # path('products/', ProductListView.as_view()),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),  # social django url for oauth etc
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('ecom_home', views.ecom_home, name='ecom_home'),
    path('messages/', include('qkchat.urls')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Views.py** from chat app 
* NOTE - if I access localhost:8000/messages/ I get the InboxView below no problem.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .forms import ComposeForm
from .models import Thread, ChatMessage


class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'qkchat/inbox.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'qkchat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = './'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**urls.py** - from chat app

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
# from qkchat import views
from .views import ThreadView, InboxView

app_name = 'qkchat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', InboxView.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ThreadView.as_view()),
]
```

**models.py** - from chat app 
*NOTE - if I remove the if username == other_username:  return None from the code below, I get the 404 Error Raised from the chap app views.py above.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import Q

class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user,
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects      = ThreadManager()

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread      = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py** - from chat app

```
from django import forms

class ComposeForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={"class": "form-control",
                }
            )
        )
```

**consumers.py** - from chat app

```
import json
import asyncio
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

from .models import Thread, ChatMessage

class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)

        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me = self.scope['user']
        # print(other_user, me)
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        self.thread_obj = thread_obj
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room

        # await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        chat_room,
        self.channel_name,
        )

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # when a message is received from the websocket
        print("receive", event)
        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            print(msg)
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = 'default'
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username,
            }
            await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)

            # broadcasts the message event to be sent
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(myResponse),
                }
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # sends the message
        print('message', event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text'],
        })


    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
        thread_obj = self.thread_obj
        # me         = self.scope['user']
        return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)
```

**thread.html** - from chat app template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<br />
<h5>Mensajes de: {% if user != object.first %}{{ object.first }}{% else %}{{ object.second }}{% endif %}</h5>
<hr>

<ul id='chat-items'>
{% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}

<li>{{ chat.message }} via {{ chat.user }}</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<form id='form' method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="myUsername" value="{{ user.username }}" />
  {{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>

</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reconnecting-websocket/1.0.0/reconnecting-websocket.js'> </script>

<script>
// websocket scripts
// console.log(window.location)
var loc = window.location
var wsStart = 'ws://'
if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)

// Below is JQuery but could be anything like Angular/React etc
var formData = $("#form")
var msgInput = $("#id_message")
var chatHolder = $("#chat-items")
var me = $("#myUsername").val()

socket.onmessage = function(e){
  console.log("message", e)
  var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
  chatHolder.append("<li>" + chatDataMsg.message + " via " + chatDataMsg.username + "</li>")
}
socket.onopen = function(e){
  console.log("open", e)
  formData.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var msgText = msgInput.val()
    // chatHolder.append("<li>" + msgText + " via " + me + "</li>")
    // var formDataSerialized = formData.serialize()
    var finalData = {
        'message': msgText
    }
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
    // msgInput.val('')
    formData[0].reset()
  })
}
socket.onerror = function(e){
  console.log("error", e)
}
socket.onclose = function(e){
  console.log("close", e)
}

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I just noticed this might be a lot to take in, and maybe I over developed without the required knowledge, but have learned alot because of this.

Thanks a lot for taking the time in advanced.

Regards

Comment: try to changeThread.objects.get_or_new to Thread.objects.get_or_create

Comment: Hey Hemanth, thanks for comment,  I changed it to get_or_create() where you mentioned and in the other applicable files (views.py, models.py and consumers.py), however the exact error comes out.  I assume the whole obj is returning None, no idea why.

Comment: Actually I get a TypeError -  get_or_create() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.  This is if I only change it in the views.py.  When I change it in the other 2 files (models & consumers), then I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a NoneType object when the logged in user tries to view their own messages.

If you login as admin and create a user named weakling and go to /messages/weakling you will have an object that is usable with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know why you are getting this error. You are entering the username of the logged in user. You have to enter other users username.

For example. I have logged as `Ajay` and I want to chat with `Vishal` so I need to enter the username in the url as `\messages\Vishal\`. Because it is written in the in the code that if the logged in `username` and `other_username` matches return None and raise Error.